# How to return JSON from a servlet based on request parameters

Tags: json, servlets

How do I use JSON in java servlet? Using the URL, to pass parameters from a POST servlet, the JSON would respond based on the URL parameters.

Comment: Duplicate of [JSON, Servlet, JSP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020311/json-servlet-jsp). If you can't find your previously asked questions, click at the nickname (user448402) at top bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"How do you use it"?

JSON is simply one way of representing hierarchical data (such an an object model) in a flat text format (such as an HTTP body, or filesystem file).  So you'd use it to represent hierarchical data in these situations.

If you mean how do you parse/create it, there are [many mature libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library) for JSON handling.

Perhaps a specific situation or use case would assist in pinning down your question, if the above is not the answer you were looking for.

Comment: How do I pass parameters from ServletOne to ServletTwo using a HTTP POST through URL intead of using HTTP GET in the servlet? 

For example: http://localhost/ServletOne?username=test

If the above link is accessed, in ServletTwo, username test will be displayed.

Answer (score 2):

You need a [JSON library](http://www.json.org/java/) in Java. With that library, you will be able to serialize Java Objects into JSON objects, and send them through `HttpServletResponse` instance in your Servlet.