# Servlet calling from window.showModalDialog(...)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jakarta-ee, servlets, lifecycle

I am calling another application context from window.showModalDialog but confused with following work. Same code to pass parameter within showModalDialg.

```
var myArguments = new Object();
myArguments.param1 = "Hello World :)";
window.showModalDialog("java2sTarget.html", myArguments, '');
```

and i can read these myArguments(parameters) in generated HTML using following code:

```
<script>
  document.write(window.dialogArguments.param1);//Hello World :)
</script>
```

I can't use query string & i am sending myArguments(parameter) because i want to hide parameter from Application user.

Now i am calling servlet from showModalDialog(..)

```
onclick="window.showModelDialog('http://localhost:7778/app/servlet/test',myArguments,'');"
```

onclick="window.showModelDialog('http://localhost:7778/app/servlet/test',myArguments,'');"

But as per my knowledge

```
Servlet  --> Servlet container --> HTML+JS+CSS
```

so JS will be available at last phase, but i want to use in first phase(Servlet).

Now, i need to make some Decision in servelt code based on myArguments(parameter).

is there any way to read these myArguments(parameters) in servlet code?

Answer (score 0):

Pass it as a request parameter in the query string.

```
var queryString = "param1=" + encodeURIComponent("Hello World :)");
onclick="window.showModelDialog('http://localhost:7778/app/servlet/test?' + queryString, myArguments, '');"
```

No, there's no other alternative. The request URL is not visible in the modal dialog anyway.

Comment: Thanks teacher, for your suggestion. i learned many things from your answers. But this time main goal to hide queryString from user.

Answer (score 0):

As main objective is to hide query string from User to avoid misuse of those parameters.
I tried following work around.

Developers send hidden parameters to get relative information form source(e.g.:DataBase). And we also know that we can send hidden information in `Window.showModalDialog` using `dialogArguments`

**Work Around:**

(i) I got relative information from server one-step before calling `Window.showModalDialog` using `jQuery.getJSON()`

(ii) i used google-gson API at servlet side to convert JavaBeans into Json strings.[Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688099/converting-json-to-java/1688182#1688182) [Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020311/json-servlet-jsp)

(iii) Convert JSON into javascript object using `jQuery.parseJSON`

```
var args = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
window.showModalDialog("pages/"+args.pageName, args, '');
```

i used `args.pageName` to make things dynamic

Please suggest improvements in this work-around. Thanks